# Android WebView full page

Tags: android, web, webview, user-agent

I am creating an aplication that involves an WebView. The thing is that I want to load the full page and not the mobile one, so I have changed the User Agent. Nevertheless there are pages that loads the mobile version.

Here are two versions of code that I have tried:

`1.webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozila ");

2.
String DESKTOP_USERAGENT = webview.getSettings().getUserAgentString ();
DESKTOP_USERAGENT = DESKTOP_USERAGENT.replace("Mobile ","");
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(DESKTOP_USERAGENT);`

This are exemples of webpages that loads the mobile version in any cases:

http://www.jurnalul.ro
http://www.androidzoom.com

1.Does anyone knows how I can trick the server and tell him I am using a desktop and not a mobile?
2.How does a website knows that I am using a mobile version?

Thank you very much,
Razvan

Comment: Have you tried replicating a whole user agent instead of modifying what's already there?

Comment: Yes I have tried and the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that if you are using a device that your carrier is routing all your HTTP requests through a proxy, and that the proxy is changing the User-Agent. Check on the other end, with your own server, using [nc -l 80 -vvv](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nc/) that your request is indeed sending the User-Agent that you have modified.

EDIT: Some specific troubleshooting steps

1. Forward a port 9090 on your router to your desktop machine or laptop.
2. Download [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)
3. Run netcat with the command "[nc -l 9090 -vvv](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nc/)"
4. In your Android application's WebView, make an HTTP request with the User-Agent you are injecting to http://your.ip.address:9090
5. In the terminal you ran netcat, you will see the HTTP request dump in plain text. There you can check the HTTP header User-Agent to see if it has been changed by a proxy server or not.

You cannot test this stuff with Wireshark or Fiddler because it is happening in the WAN. You need to test it on the receiving end, either on a server, or on your own desktop machine.

Comment: Well this is a general situation. When I enter on those websites with the mobile browser is the same situation. Untill now this happend only for this 2 websites. For other websites like www.google.ro, www.earthcam.com si working like it should. I have made a test on http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ and the result was that I was using the Desktop user agent.

Comment: Could you post the whole HTTP request as seen by using the nc command? Also there could be a JavaScript based redirect on those sites.

Comment: It crossed my mind that could be a Javascript on the page that gets the screen size and so will redirect to mobile version, so I have disabled the Javascript but still nothing. I am not sure at what you are refering by "Could you post the whole HTTP request as seen by using the nc command?"

Comment: Is there a possibility that the webpage identifies the Operating system and then redirect to the mobile version? If is true how I can change the name of the operating system that is transmited?

Comment: Forward a port to your desktop machine from your router, say port 9090. Then download the tool "netcat" and run it on your desktop on port 9090 with the command I gave you. Then, connect to that port on your LAN's IP from your browser and read the output, then paste it to us. Or, you can do this on a VPS.

Comment: I think I have confused you. My program is created for Android operating system. All the things I wrote are for the mobile browser not for a desktop browser. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: No, I haven't been confused. I meant exactly what I said.

Comment: Point the web view at a server running netcat, and dump the http request to standard output.

Comment: Thank you Tom for your clear explanation. I went through the steps you described and this the HTTTP request:        listening on [any] 9090 ...
213.233.85.4: inverse host lookup failed: h_errno 11004: NO_DATA
connect to [86.123.179.93] from (UNKNOWN) [213.233.85.4] 49049: NO_DATA
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 86.123.179.93:9090
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US
x-wap-profile: http://gsm.lge.com/html/gsm/P350-M6-D2.xml
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,i
mage/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7

Comment: Does the website reads x-wap-profile and because of this the I am redirected to the mobile version? If is true how can I change the x-wap-profile in Android?

Answer (score 1):

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);//for desktop 1 or mobil 0.
```

Comment: The setting .setUserAgent does not exist.

Comment: Yes it look like it is remove by sdk17. http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes/android.webkit.WebSettings.html